# It's impossible to focus on these windows with keyboard shortcuts

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

I've been working without a mouse for several days and almost everything has been fairly easy to manage with keyboard shortcuts.

There are two exceptions:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I'm unable to find a keyboard shortcut that moves the focus to either of these windows.

(EDIT I am on macOS Mojava)

I've tried:

- Cmd-Tab
- Control-Tab from Finder
- Shortcat
- ^F6 (floating window)

How can I focus (close/dismiss) these windows using only the keyboard?

I could, obviously, use some keyboard control of the mouse, but that's generally a very long and slow process, and it really feels like there should be a better way...

Comment: I don’t know, but I find it frustrating that macOS has never been fully accessible without a mouse. What version of macOS are you using? That might help someone find an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any shortcut, but there is a workaround how you can use keyboard only to focus it. You may [enable mouse keys](https://support.apple.com/en-lk/guide/mac-help/mh27469/mac) - press 5 times Alt key and then use keyboard to move the cursor.

Alternatively you may install some third party tool to control the mouse. My recommendation goes to [Karabiner Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/), because I use it for bunch of other useful staff. Once you install it you should  add [Mouse Keys Mode](https://ke-complex-modifications.pqrs.org/#mouse_keys_mode_v4).

There is also https://github.com/h2ero/XEasyMotion   but I haven't used it personally.